# Does a node receive messages sent by itself on a topic that it is both publishing and subscribing to?

Tags: ros, rospy, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on writing some code for a project, but I have a node that will be continuously publishing(30 Hz) to a topic while also subscribing to the same topic to listen for a different pub from a different node.   Basically, node A is listening to topic X and publishing to topic X. Meanwhile another node, node B, will at some time, publish a message to topic X. Will the subscriber callback in node A be triggered every time it publishes sometime? Also, will it be able to pick up the message if node B only publishes once?
Thanks,
luketheduke

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233326/does-a-node-receive-messages-sent-by-itself-on-a-topic-that-it-is-both-publishing-and-subscribing-to?/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2016-04-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-01**:
May I suggest a title change? Your question seems to be really about whether a node receives its own messages if it publishes on a topic it also subscribes to. You can't actually 'receive callbacks', just messages.

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-05-01**:
Thanks for the suggestion! It's changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a node publishes on a topic and also has a subscriber for it, it will receive "it's own" message. This is a feature, as components in the publish/subscribe system should not need to care about where a message originates from.

Even though this probably is best avoided, you can check for the origin of a message using the [MessageEvent](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1MessageEvent.html#_details) mechanism (e.g. if it originates from the same node) as in [this example](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/vehicle_controller/blob/master/src/controller.cpp#L233).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-04-30**:
Thanks for the quick reply!